# Printf appending fails

Tags: bash, text-processing, echo, printf

I Tried to run the following similar commands in CentOS (12.x):

```
printf "\nhello" "$HOME"/.bashrc
printf "\nhello" ${HOME}/.bashrc
```

After execution I display the content of the `.bashrc` file and see nothing new.

`set -x` brings an empty line of output for both so my command is likely wrong.

I had a similar problem with `echo` syntax (edit: I'm likely to misrecall but I recalled I could append content with `echo` without appendation operator like >>).

What you see wrong?

Comment: You are missing a redirection operator...

Comment: I swear I remembered in the past I used `echo` without it and still appended content.

Comment: @user9303970 Using `echo` without redirection would not append text to any file, unless the `echo` was part of a composite command that was redirected as a whole, or a redirected script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to redirect the output to your `.bashrc` file you need a redirection operator `>` (will overwrite the file) or in your case `>>` (will append the file) is probably more appropriate.

```
printf '\n%s\n' "hello" >> "${HOME}/.bashrc"
```

A Kusalananda points out it's generally a good idea to put a trailing newline at the end of your file.  Some tools expect a file to end with a newline and could behave unexpectedly if it's not there.